# Apache Cordova doesn't load all page div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm developing an app with PhoneGap and I want to create a simple between some pages.

This is my html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Prova</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>


</head>

<body>


<div class="prima" data-role="page" id="article1">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <h1>Articles</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Article 1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="prima" data-role="page" id="article2">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
    <h1>Articles</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Article 2</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="prima" data-role="page" id="article3">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
    <h1>Articles</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Article 3</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery_mobile.js"></script>
<script src="js/gianni.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My js file is (http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NV6Py/)

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.prima', function(event){    
if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once


{    
    var nextpage = $(this).next('.prima');
    console.log(nextpage);
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
    }
    event.handled = true;
}
return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '.prima', function(event){   
if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
{      
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('.prima');
    console.log(prevpage);

    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse:      true}, true, true);
    }
    event.handled = true;
}
return false;            
});
```

When I open this html file it works and read all page div  but if I use this page in my app where I have some pages before arrive to this page the swipe doesn't work because var nextpage = $(this).next('.prima') is empy and if I check with Ispector in html there is only the fist div and no other (ex. article2, article3)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but unfortunately I can't comment on your question because of my low reputation. So I can't ask you for more clarification.

But you have 3 divs all with the class: prima. And your problem is that you can only see the first div, so the div with the id: article1.

The reason why you can only see one div, is because you use the `data-role: page`. You are creating a page, and you can only see one page at the time.

Comment: Hi Reptar, I'm using this example
 http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NV6Py/

But if I open only this two page the swipe works. But if I use this page in my app where I have some pages before arrive to this page the swipe doesn't work because 
    var nextpage = $(this).next('.prima')
is empy and if I check with Ispector in html there is only the fist div and no other (ex. article2, article3)

Comment: Oke, so what I see, is that your code works when you slide from page 1 to 2, and 2 to 3, but when you want to slide back, it doesn't work?

Comment: Reptar If you give me your mail I can send you the project to understand. Because it's very hard to explain but if you look it is easier.

Comment: I get the idea, have the same problem when I wan't to "slide back", I will try to fix it within the JSfiddle